# Readers-writers problem, is there any simple adjustments I can do?

Tags: python, multithreading

So I know writers release the priority lock too early. The lock should only be released by a writer if it knows that no other writer is in the queue. For example, if a writer is now executing in its critical state, the next writer will be stuck on resource_lock. The next reader will also be stuck on resource_lock. Since both the next writer and reader are now waiting for access to the >same< lock (resource_lock), there is no longer any priority for either thread type. When resource_lock is unlocked by the first writer, either reader or writer can enter.
How do I solve this in the easiest way?

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock
from datetime import datetime
import time


priority_lock = Lock() #priority lock
reader_lock = Lock() #lock for readers
# writer_lock = Lock() #lock for writers
resource_lock = Lock() #Lock for RESOURCE
reader_counter = 0

resource = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

class Reader(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global reader_counter
        while(True):
            #check
            priority_lock.acquire()
            priority_lock.release()

            with reader_lock: 
                reader_counter += 1
                if reader_counter == 1: 
                    resource_lock.acquire()
            
            print("Reader: " + resource)

            with reader_lock:
                reader_counter -=1
                if reader_counter == 0:
                    resource_lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.1)



class ReversedWriter(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global resource
        while True:
            priority_lock.acquire()
            priority_lock.release()

            resource_lock.acquire()
            resource = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            reverse = datetime.now().strftime("%S:%M:%H")
            print("ReversedWriter " + reverse)
            resource_lock.release()
            
            time.sleep(0.1)

class Writer(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global resource
        while True:
            priority_lock.acquire()
            priority_lock.release()

           
            resource_lock.acquire()
            resource = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       
            print("Writer " + resource) 
            resource_lock.release()
            
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
R1 = Reader()
R2 = Reader()
R3 = Reader()

W1 = Writer()
W2 = ReversedWriter()

R1.start()
R2.start()
R3.start()
W1.start()
W2.start()
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `priority_lock`? It seems you only ever acquire and release it without doing anything. And just to clarify, you're trying to give readers priority over writers?

Comment: @BoppreH The purpose of `priority_lock` is to give writers priority over readers, but there lies the problem as the lock is released too early.

Comment: Writers aren't supposed to have *priority* over readers. Rather, they request *exclusive* access to a resource, rather than *inclusive* access. If you request exclusive access, you still need to wait for readers with inclusive access to finish, but other readers requesting access *after* you do not block you. When one writer releases the exclusive access lock, that doesn't mean the next writer gets it immediately, only that they *can* get it once the readers ahead of it finish.

Comment: It doesn't really mean anything to acquire and immediately release a lock without doing something in between.

Comment: I think what you want is the solution to the [third readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers–writers_problem). Basically, readers and writers both get in the same line. When a reader reaches the front, they wait for a writer to finish or for "enough" readers to finish to give them access. When a writer reaches the front, they wait for *all* readers or the writer to finish, then get access. In both cases, the next actor (whether reader or writer) block everyone behind them in line.